# MVC5 - Request.Browser information - Reports wrong type for Chrome on iOS

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 (C#) application. When a user hits the home page, I log the hit, along with the user's browser information. The C# code looks as follows:

```
if (!Request.Browser.Crawler && Request.UserHostAddress != "::1")
{
    Entities.SiteActivity siteActivity = new SiteActivity() 
    {
        Address = Request.UserHostAddress,
        BrowserMajorVersion = Request.Browser.MajorVersion.ToString(),
        BrowserMinorVersion = Request.Browser.MinorVersion.ToString(),
        BrowserName = Request.Browser.Browser,
        BrowserPlatform = Request.Browser.Platform,
        BrowserType = Request.Browser.Type,
        Page = "Home",
        Url = Request.Url.ToString()
    };

    this.SiteActivityData.Save(siteActivity);
```

When I hit the page from my iPad using Chrome, the browser name and type is 'Safari', and the Platform registers as Unknown. I'm curious why the Chrome browser on iOS is sending information that it's Safari, and why the platform doesn't show as iOS? Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

Comment: All browsers on iOS devices use Safari's underpinnings (per Apple requirements).  They're just shells over that, giving you better tab management and such (or, in Chrome's case, the connections to your Google account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

51Degrees.Mobi offers advanced device detection.  It may help you.

This blog from Steve Sanderson is very useful too.

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/12/17/using-51degreesmobi-foundation-for-accurate-mobile-browser-detection-on-aspnet-mvc-3/